# rpm macros on CentOS 6.5

Tags: rpm, centos

Trying to create a spec file for a CentOS 6.5 system.  The rpm should check release to add specific Requires: lines based on the OS version....and it doesn't work at all:

Spec file snippet:

```
%if 0%{?rhel} == 6
Requires: packageName
%endif
%description
Check dependencies and make OS modifications. 

%files
```

/etc/rpm/macros.dist:

```
# dist macros.

%rhel 6
%centos 6
%centos_ver 6
%dist .el6
%el6 1
```

According to many web pages I've been to, the code should work but I never get a message that packageName is required when installing the rpm..What am I missing here??

**UPDATE...**

Reinstalled my system and everything works OK now..Something must have mess up my environment on my test system...My original code now works

Comment: Does this seem applicable (use el6)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135502/rpmbuild-dist-not-defined-on-centos-5-5

Comment: I saw that post..My RPM still doesn't add the Requires: line..

Comment: Something was wrong with my original environment..After reinstalling the code in my post worked perfectly.

Comment: Funny how those things work. But glad you resolved your issue.

Answer (score 4):

`%{?rhel}` will expand to `6`.  Therefore `0%{?rhel}` will expand to `06` and it shouldn't match `6`.

You probably want instead:

```
%if 0%{?rhel}
   Requires: packageName
%endif
%description
Check dependencies and make OS modifications. 

%files
```

This will expand to `0` if `%{rhel}` not defined and it will expand to `06` if it is defined.  In spec-file-land, `0` is a false value and `06` is a true value.

Or, if you only want to match RHEL/CENTOS 6.X (instead of all RHELs/CENTOSs), use this, following the same logic as above:

```
%if 0%{?el6}
   Requires: packageName
%endif
%description
Check dependencies and make OS modifications. 

%files
```