# How can I find where an RPM macro is defined or what it expands to?

Tags: rpm, macro

Inside of an RPM I have

```
%{__install} %{SOURCE2} %{buildroot}
```

I believe that `%{__install}` is a macro. Where do I find where it is defined? What is the definition? Was it provided by the system or distro, or is it a core rpm thing?

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/350842/117549 help? Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145999/117549

Comment: `rpm --showrc | grep __install` will certainly show its definition. There is a `macros` file (among many others) in `/usr/lib/rpm` (usually): the definition can be found in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `__install` as an example you can see where it's defined with

```
rpm --showrc | grep __install
```

Or you can see the definition with

```
rpm --eval "%{__install}"
```